# jqgrid - sending search results to a cfc

Tags: search, jqgrid, coldfusion

Hi I'm using a custom button to send the results of a search to the server.
Works great in FF and Chrome. In Internet Explorer the grid is updated to reflect  the search but the results coming back from the server are always the same. They are actually always the same as the result of the first search. I'm guessing that the filter criteria $grid[0].p.postData.filters isn't getting updated before its sent to the server.

```
      $grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-copy", title: "Export",
      onClickButton: function() {
          $.post("scripts/scraprecords.cfc?method=getRecordsExcel&returnFormat=json", {_search:$grid[0].p.search, filters:$grid[0].p.postData.filters}, function(res) {
            var h = "<a href='temp/"+res+"'><img src='images/download-button.png' border='0'></a>"
            var $dialog = $('<div align=center></div>')
                .html('Your Report has been generated.<br>'+h)
                .dialog({autoOpen: true,title: 'Information',closeText:'hide',show:'slide',modal: true});
            },"json");
      }
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Mark

Comment: The data being sent to the server was correct. It was Internet Explorer caching the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Check this previous discussion about jqGrid and IE caching.

[jqGrid data stored in browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885658/jqgrid-data-stored-in-browser-cache)