# need to get filters and sorting behavior from jqgrid for a different hidden field

Tags: jqgrid, filter, http-post

I have a form on my page that is submitting independently of the jqgrid.  I need to get any filters and the sorting behavior of the grid as it is currently loaded on the client and include that in my post data that I'm sending up to the server so that it can perform what it needs to perform using the same searching criteria.

I tried this to no avail:

```
$("#settings").val($("#list").getGridParam("postData"));
```

where settings is the id of a hidden field in my form.  It does indeed pass in the gridsettings object to back end, but it's not including any of my filters and sorting behavior.

any suggestions?

**EDIT:** when I do console.log($("#settings").val()); in firefox it's showing the correct filters and searching criteria.  I'm using the same object on the back end that I do for the actual grid and it's just not working.  Do I need to change that object somehow since I'm posting this through a regular http post and not an ajax postback?

**EDIT 2:**  if you read the comments under Oleg's post, you'll see how I resolved this.  I had to pass each property separately that is held within the object created by getGridParam().  I am marking his answer as the correct answer as his comments lead me down the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you could solve the problem by adding

```js
searchoptions: {searchhidden: true}
```

for hidden columns in `colModel` which can be used during searching. If you want to set the settings for all columns you can use `cmTemplate` option of jqGrid:

```js
cmTemplate: {searchoptions: {searchhidden: true}}
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details about `cmTemplate`.

Comment: I assume that goes on the grid declaration.  I put it there and am getting the same result.  Do I need to do something special to set a hidden html form field to an object?  I think what's happening is that it's passing an actual string through that just says "[object]" when the form posts for the value of my hidden field (settings).

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson: You don't posted the code which you use, so it's difficult to understand what you do. The problem with `[object]` seems me very easy. `$("#list").getGridParam("postData")` is really object. The `filters` property of the object represent JSON version of the filter. So if you want display if you should use `console.log($("#list").getGridParam("postData").filters);`. If you need to set such filter manually you have to set additionally `search: true` option of jqGrid.

Comment: I've just looked at the headers that are being sent when jqgrid is called initially and it looks like it passes all of the items in the object (_search, rows, page, sidx, etc) as separate variables in the request header.  I'm guessing that is where my problem is coming into play is that I'm just trying to send one object that has all of those properties already set.  I'm going to try to split them out and see what happens.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson: Sorry, but I am not sure that I understand you correctly because you don't send any JavaScript code which you use to create the grid. If you need get the current filter you can use `$("#list").getGridParam("postData").filters`. If you need to have current sorting column (`sidx`) you need use `$("#list").getGridParam("sortname")`. To get sorting direction you should use `$("#list").getGridParam("sortorder")` and so on (`page`, `rowNum`, `search` options). Is it what you need?

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson: It's just a timestamp which will be used to make every request to the server different. If you control caching with respect of `Cache-Control` options of the HTTP header of the server response (for example `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0`) you can use `prmNames: {nd: null}` to remove sending of the option. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3885956/315935) for some more details.