# loadonce:true causing issues in paging for jqGrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid as mentioned below:

**UsersList.aspx**

```html
<div id="users" class="grid-right">
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <table id="client-group-users-list"></table>
    <div id="client-group-users-list-pager"></div>
</div>
```

**userlistgroup.js**

```js
function createUsersGrid(getUsersForClientGroupUrl) {
    $('#client-group-users-list').jqGrid({
        height: "auto",
        width: "590",
        url: getUsersForClientGroupUrl + "?random=" + Math.random(),
        rowNum: 10,
        mtype: 'POST',
        viewrecords: true,
        postData: { clientGroup: getClientGroupId(), active: true },
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['ClientGroupID', 'Login', 'Role'],
        //pgbuttons: false,
        //pgtext: null,
        //viewrecords: false,
        gridview: true,
        colModel: [
            { name: 'ClientGroupID', index: 'ClientGroupID', hidden: true },
            { name: 'Login', index: 'Login', search: false, width: 130, sorttype: "string" },
            { name: 'Role', index: 'Role', search: false, width: 100 }
        ],
        caption: "Users for client group: " + getClientGroupName(),
        pager: '#client-group-users-list-pager',
        ondblClickRow: function (userId) {
            editUser(userId);
        },
        sortname: 'Login',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        loadui: 'enable',
        loadError: function (xhr, status) {
            location.reload();
        }           
    })
    .jqGrid('navGrid', '#client-group-users-list-pager',
        { add: false, del: false, edit: false, search: false, view: false })
}
```

[image]

Sorting on the `Login` column is not working. However if I put `loadonce:true` then it starts working but the total number of records are not reflected and paging functionality gets stops working.

Can any one help me out in handling both sorting and paging working together with `datatype: 'json'`.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you have typical understanding problems how jqGrid interact with the server.

If you use `datatype: 'json'` **without `loadonce: true` option** then *the server* is responsible for sorting, paging and optionally searching/filtering of the data. In the case **every request to the server** contains important input parameters which default values are: `page`, `rows`, `sidx` and `sord`. There are other parameters `_search`, `nd` and some other, but there are not so important in your case. So at the first loading on the grid content jqGrid post to the URL `getUsersForClientGroupUrl` somthing like

```
page=1&rows=10&sidx=Login&sord=asc
```

The values of `rows`, `sidx` and `sord` parameters corresponds the values of `rowNum`, `sortname` and `sortorder` options which you use. The sever should provide **requested page of data** (the 1-st page of data, the size of the page is 10 rows). One can use `prmNames` option of the grid to rename `page`, `rows`, `sidx` and `sord` parameters.

It's important to understand that when the user click on the "Next Page"/Previous Page" buttons or if the user click on the column header to change the sorting then jqGrid makes **new request to the server** and the server should provide the page of data based on the input parameters.

On the other side **if you use `loadonce: true` option** then the server should return **all the data (all pages)**. The loaded data should be just sorted corresponds with `sidx` and `sord` options. After loading of the data **jqGrid change `datatype` from `"json"` to `"local"`**. All next sorting, paging and filtering (see [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) method) or sorting (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)) will be implemented by jqGrid internally (on the client side).

If you need reload the data from the server you should reset the value of `datatype` to `"json"` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/315935)). Typically one do this inside of [beforeRefresh](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) callback of `navGrid`. So the grid will be reloaded from the server if the user clicks on the "Refresh" button of the navigator bar.

I supposed that you just not changed your server code and the server still returns *one page* of data when you use `loadonce: true` option. It's wrong. Don't forget to sort initial data on the server.

Some common problems in the code which you posted. I recommend you remove `"?random=" + Math.random()` part from the URL because it has no sense. Such method are used typically to prevent caching of server respond in case of usage `mtype: "GET"` (HTTP GET verb). You use `mtype: 'POST'`. So the response will not changed at all. Moreover if you would use `mtype: "GET"` then jqGrid append already URL with `nd` parameter which have the same role as your `random` parameter. The best way is to set `Cache-Control` HTTP headers of the server response to `private, max-age=0` and to remove `nd` with `prmNames: { nd: null }` jqGrid option. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269567/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885956/315935) for more information about caching.

Another problem: you should understand that you can call `createUsersGrid` function **only once**. After it the `<table>` with `id="client-group-users-list"` will be modified. The next call of `createUsersGrid` function will do just nothing. One should consider whether one need to place JavaScript fragment in the function if it could be called only once. Alternatively one can use `GridUnload` method to destroy all existing jqGrid structures before usage it at the next time.

If you want that `clientGroup: getClientGroupId()` parameter which will be sent to the server are

Comment: Cool explanation with details. It helped me a lot to understand the problem of loadonce very well.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. for me it was server code. I was returning only for first page.

```
rows = model.Select(x => new { x.POID,  
                                         x.HA1.HA1,   
                                         x.PONumber,
                                           status = x.POStatu.Name,
                                         vendor=x.Vendor.Name,  
                                         x.POCreatedDate,
                                         x.POSenttoVendor 
                                       }  
                             ).ToArray().ToPagedList(pageIndex,pageSize).
```

so ,I removed 
    .ToPagedList(pageIndex,pageSize)

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete with an example.

Hi people, I passed to the same problem and I couldn't see any example of this. So, I solved my problem and I'll let you a example.

I have a table named "estado"(id, nome, sigla, codigo_ibge). I implemented the jqGrid Guriddo Responsive to make all CRUD actions.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../../resources/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-pt-br.js"></script>

    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../../resources/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

    <!-- A link to a Boostrap  and jqGrid Bootstrap CSS siles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../resources/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />

    <style type="text/css">  
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
              position: relative; 
              margin: 0em; 
              padding:0; 
              /*overflow: auto;*/ 
              overflow-x:hidden; 
              overflow-y:auto; 
              text-align:left;
          } 
         .customelement .radio-inline input {
             margin-left: -40px;
             padding-right: 10px; 
         }
         .typeahead {
             z-index: 10051;
         }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.defaults.width = 850;
        $.jgrid.defaults.responsive = true;
        $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap';
        $.jgrid.styleUI.Bootstrap.base.rowTable = "table table-bordered table-striped";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: '../ctrl_gerenciamento/gerenciaEstadoJqGridLoad.php',
                editurl: '../ctrl_gerenciamento/gerenciaEstadoJqGridEdit.php',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
                page: 1,
                jsonReader: {
                    page: "obj.currpage",
                    total: "obj.totalpages",
                    records: "obj.totalrecords",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: "obj.rows",
                    cell: "cell",
                    id: "0"
                },
                colModel: [
                    {
                        label: 'ID',
                        name: 'id',
                        width: 20,
                        key: true,
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Nome',
                        name: 'nome',
                        width: 145,
                        editable: true,
                        editrules : { required: true },
                        search: true,
                        stype: 'text'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Sigla',
                        name: 'sigla',
                        width: 35,
                        editable: true,
                        editrules : { required: true },
                        search: true,
                        stype: 'text'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Código IBGE',
                        name: 'codigo_ibge',
                        width: 60,
                        editable: true,
                        editrules : { required: true },
                        search: true,
                        stype: 'text'
                    }
                ],
                sortname: 'nome',
                sortorder : 'asc',
                loadonce: false,
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 785,
                height: 370,
                rowNum: 10,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });

            $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {defaultSearch:'cn'});

            $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navGrid',"#jqGridPager", 
                { 
                    edit: true, 
                    add: true, 
                    del: true, 
                    search: false, 
                    refresh: false, 
                    view: false, 
                    position: "left"
                },
                {
                    editCaption: "Editar",
                    width: "500",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "120",
                    left: "500",
                    recreateForm: true,
                    closeAfterEdit: true,
                    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                    }
                },
                {
                    editCaption: "Adicionar",
                    width: "500",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "120",
                    left: "500",
                    closeAfterAdd: true,
                    recreateForm: true,
                    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                    }
                },
                {
                    editCaption: "Apagar",
                    width: "500",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "120",
                    left: "500",
                    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <h4> Gerenciamento de Estados </h4>
    <br />
    <div style="margin-left:10px">
        <table id="jqGrid"></table>
        <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**LOAD controller from the server:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    include_once '../../classes/start.php';
    $json = new JSON();

    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $limit = $_GET['rows'];
    $sidx = $_GET['sidx'];
    $sord = $_GET['sord'];

    $_search = $_GET['_search'];
    $filtro = array();
    $filtro["nome"]         = isset($_GET["nome"]) ? $_GET["nome"] : null;
    $filtro["sigla"]        = isset($_GET["sigla"]) ? $_GET["sigla"] : null;
    $filtro["id"]           = isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : null;
    $filtro["codigo_ibge"]  = isset($_GET["codigo_ibge"]) ? $_GET["codigo_ibge"] : null;

    try
    {
        if (!$sidx) $sidx = 1;

        $result = Estado::contarTodosRegistros();
        $qtdRegistros = $result[0]['count'];

        if ($qtdRegistros > 0 && $limit > 0) {
            $total_pages = ceil($qtdRegistros / $limit);
        } else {
            $total_pages = 0;
        }

        if ($page > $total_pages) $page = $total_pages;

        $start = $limit*$page - $limit;
        if ($start < 0) $start = 0;

        $result = null;
        $saida = null;

        if ($_search) {
            $result = Estado::consultarTodosRegistros($sidx, $sord, $start, $limit, $filtro);
        }else{
            $result = Estado::consultarTodosRegistros($sidx, $sord, $start, $limit);
        }
        $saida["rows"] = $result;
        $saida["totalrecords"] = "$qtdRegistros";
        $saida["currpage"] = "$page";
        $saida["totalpages"] = "$total_pages";

        $json->setStatus("ok");
        $json->setObjeto( $saida );
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        $json->setStatus("erro");
        $json->setMensagem($ex->getMessage());
    }

    $json->imprimirJSON();
```

**The Method that works on the search:**

```
public static function consultarTodosRegistros($sidx, $sord, $start, $limit, $filtro='')
    {
        $db = Database::conexao();
        $temp = 'where 1=1';
        if (!empty($filtro)){
            if (!empty($filtro["nome"])) {
                $temp .= " and estado.nome ilike '%". $filtro["nome"]."%'";
            }
            if (!empty($filtro["sigla"])) {
                $temp .= " and estado.sigla ilike '%". $filtro["sigla"]."%'";
            }
            if (!empty($filtro["id"])) {
                $temp .= " and estado.id = ". $filtro["id"];
            }
            if (!empty($filtro["codigo_ibge"])) {
                $temp .= " and estado.codigo_ibge ilike '%". $filtro["codigo_ibge"]."%'";
            }
        }
        $sql = "select *
                from updrs.estado
                $temp
                order by $sidx $sord
                limit $limit offset $start";

        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

**EDIT/ADD/DEL operator**

```
<?php
include_once '../../classes/start.php';

$operacao = $_POST["oper"];

$id = !empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
$codigoIbge = isset($_POST["codigo_ibge"]) ? $_POST["codigo_ibge"] : null;
$sigla = isset($_POST["sigla"]) ? $_POST["sigla"] : null;
$nome = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? $_POST["nome"] : null;

if ($operacao == 'add')
{
    try
    {
        $idResult = Estado::insert($codigoIbge, $sigla, $nome);
        echo "registro atualizado: " . $idResult;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ($operacao == 'edit')
{
    try
    {
        $count = Estado::update($codigoIbge, $sigla, $nome, $id);
        echo $count . " registro atualizado.";
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Erro: Dados informados são inválidos";
    }

}

if ($operacao == 'del')
{
    try
    {
        $count = Estado::delete($id);
        echo $count . " registro apagado.";
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Erro: Remoção do registro não permitida";
    }
}
```

I hope helped with a real example. Enjoy.