# how to override the default query string parameters in ajax request vai jqgrid

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

The bellow is my jqGrid config:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: '/Panel/Article/latest_articles_json',
    datatype: 'json',
    fitWindow: SITE.FITWINDOW,
    postData: {},
    height: $(window).height() - 260,
    width: $(window).width() + SITE.FITWINDOW[0],
    altRows:true,
    gridview: true,
    colNames: colNames,
    colModel: colModel,
    autowidth: true,
    pager: '#page',
    page: 1,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList: [50,100,200],
    rowNum: 50,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    cmTemplate: {sortable:false},
    jsonReader: {
        root: 'data.items',
        records: 'data.records',
        total: 'data.totalsize',
        page: 'data.page',
        id: 'id'
    }
});
```

When I run my web application it result with query string parameters
it requests as ajax with parameters

```
_search:false
nd:1460779456815
rows:50
page:1
sidx:
sord:asc
```

Now I have the question with how I can override the query string of `"sord:asc" to change to "sord:desc"`

And I am tried to modify the config: `url: '/Panel/Article/latest_articles_json?sord:desc',` but it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The values of parameters `sord` and `sidx` come from the jqGrid options `sortorder` and `sortname`. Thus you should add `sortorder: "desc"` option to have `sord=desc` instead of `sord=asc`.

To control *the names* and the existence of other default parameters sent to the server one should use `prmNames` option. For example

```
prmNames: { nd: null, search: "isSearch" }
```

removes `nd` parameter (like`nd=1460779456815`) and to rename `_search` parameters to `isSearch`. I recommend to set `cache-control: private, max-age=0` as HTTP header (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885956/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269567/315935)).